# transfer files to local from remote machine A via remote machine B

Tags: networking, server, ssh, sftp, scp

I must transfer several huge files from a remote machine A to my local computer. The problem is that I can not access A directly, but instead I must access via another remote machine B. Unfortunately, machine B has a very limited amount of space, so I can not copy the files from A to B and then from B to local. Instead, I would need to use B as a kind of proxy.

I was thinking in something as simple as possible that does not need to install or configure anything, hopefully simply using `sftp`, `scp` o `ssh`.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I can't access from A to local either. I have been looking at the SSH tunnel thing, but on one hand I can't find clear documentation and on another it seems I would need root privileges on B, which I haven't (on both A and B I am a simple user).

Comment: Use B as Jumphost and then you can use sftp or scp to/from A via B.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! After looking into pLumo's suggestions, I found that

`sftp -o "ProxyJump userB@serverB" userA@serverA`

did the trick! Thanks a lot!